# How to extract a json object in an excel column using python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have an excel file with one of the columns as json array. I want to extract the value of "name" from the object against the particular "sid".Below is the input:

| SID | Sumary |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | [{'xid': 'Dseabc101', 'name': 'event1'}, {'xid': '5Radesc', 'name': 'Event2'}] |
| 102 | [{'xid': '3a65a2', 'name': 'Event3'}] |

The expected output should be:
[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Does the column contain strings (text in the JSON format), or does it contain already-parsed JSON data?

Comment: It contains parsed json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Summary'] = df['Summary'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(y['name'] for y in x))
```

---

```
df['Summary'] = [','.join(y['name'] for y in x) for x in df['Summary']]
```

If possible strings in column `Summary` use:

```
import ast

df['Summary']=df['Summary'].apply(lambda x:','.join(y['name'] for y in ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

Or:

Comment: Thank you for the timely response, it resolved the issue.